# "No app configured" error while using WebApplicationFactory for running integration tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-5.0

I am writing integration tests for my app which uses .net5 I have used WebApplicationFactory with IHostBuilder for setting up environment.

Custom fixture ->

```
public class TestFixture<T> : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
       var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();
       builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
       {
           var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
           config.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath);
           config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
           config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
       })
       .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => { services.Configure(hostContext); });
       return builder;
   }
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureTestServices((services) =>
    {
        services.RemoveAll(typeof(IHostedService));
    });
}
```

}

services.Configure(hostContext) calls UnityContainer which registers workflows(https://github.com/danielgerlag/workflow-core).

Test class(gives error when test is run)-> [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gXVo.png)

Error desc -> No application configured. Please specify an application via IWebHostBuilder.UseStartup, IWebHostBuilder.Configure, or specifying the startup assembly via StartupAssemblyKey in the web host configuration

Comment: Why are you using a package exclusively created for testing ASP.NET Core applications when you are not using ASP.NET Core? This approach makes no sense.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto What should I use to add integration tests in this scenario? My app is a console app with target framework .net 5 and there are two HostBuilder running which are used to add two hosted services. One is used to read messages from a queue and add to db and other reads db and starts workflow as mentioned in original question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this code : `.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(b => b.Configure(app => {}));`
after        `.ConfigureServices` call

you are using a Worker Service that doesn't run a web host. However, the WebApplicationFactory still expects one, So create an empty web application.

Comment: Great answer! This was not obvious at all.

Answer (score 0):

@Vaibhav's answer above was very helpful but still not super obvious on how to apply if working directly with WebApplicationFactory in .Net6+ using minimal hosting. Hopefully this is helpful to someone else...

```cs
using WebApplicationFactory<Program> webApplicationFactory = 
    new WebApplicationFactory<Program>()
        .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            builder.Configure(_ => { });
        });
```

Without that empty configure, you will get the following error and it was driving me mad!

```cs
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No application configured. 
Please specify an application via IWebHostBuilder.UseStartup, 
IWebHostBuilder.Configure, or specifying the startup assembly 
via StartupAssemblyKey in the web host configuration.'
```

Comment: This post has been viewed over 3400 times as of today, so I'm going to assume devs are being directed here in their quest to create an end-to-end test of a .net worker service. If this is you, please have a look at my answer on how you can use WebApplicationFactory to accomplish this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77734096/4465532