# Is there an equivalent for WebApplicationFactory for a .NET Core console app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, console-application, .net-6.0

I am creating integration tests for a .NET 6.0 C# console application.  Is there a way to test it in the same way ASP.NET Core uses `WebApplicationFactory` to host and test the app? I would like to be able to change some of the dependency injection services when running my tests in the same way that you can with `WebApplicationFactory`, so simply running the console application or calling the `Program.Main` method isn't what I'm looking for.

I understand you couldn't use `CreateClient` and communicate with the console app using an `HttpClient`, but maybe keyboard inputs could be piped to it.

Currently I am using `Process` to manually launch it and capture the output, which works to an extent but does not provide a straightforward way to customize dependency injection, different configurations, mocking, stubbing, fakes etc. as `WebApplicationFactory` provides for web applications.

Comment: Why would you want to test a console app "as you would an ASP.NET Core"? How about just testing it as a console app?

Comment: Please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75971456/2501279) (first dupe). There is no need to use `Process` just switch to old generation template and run `Main` method, alternatively you can  use `Assembly.EntryPoint` (see the second dupe).

Comment: @Sweeper Because hosting the console app in-process would allow for testing 
dependency injection customization and configuration changes, mocking and faking, and so forth

Comment: Whoever marked this as a duplicate doesn't understand the question.  I am not trying to run the Console Main() method directly, and it is nothing to to with top-level statements.    I am trying to host it WebApplicationFactory style, for reasons described in my above comment.

Comment: @AlanClark I've edited so we can try and remove the duplicates. I'm looking to do the same thing as yourself so would help if this question was marked duplicate when it's not

Comment: "hosting the console app in-process" is equivalent to adding a reference to that assembly and calling its public methods. Testing will be a *lot* easier if you don't put too much logic in `main`. Testing is easier too if you use a command-line parsing library. Many integrate with the Generic Host.  Almost all of them use either command classes or call lambdas to handle command verbs. This means you can test individual commands independently, using your own Generic host

Comment: There is far too much reading on this post.  I think you're looking for the out-of-the-box background worker template. Try: `dotnet new worker`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the Worker Service template instead of a plain console app and you will get dependency injection and configuration for free. Here's how you can extend `WebApplicationFactory` for end-to-end testing your host application.

```cs
public class HostApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> : WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> 
    where TEntryPoint : class
{
    private readonly Action<IWebHostBuilder> _configuration;

    public HostApplicationFactory(Action<IWebHostBuilder> configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder) =>
        _configuration(builder.Configure(_ => { }));

    public Task RunHostAsync()
    {
        var host = Services.GetRequiredService<IHost>();
        return host.WaitForShutdownAsync();
    }
}
```

And how to use it...

```cs
await using HostApplicationFactory<Program> hostApplicationFactory =
    new(configuration: builder =>
    {
        // Replace any appsettings like dynamic ports from test containers
        builder.UseSetting("SomeAppSetting:Key", "replacement value");

        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            // Override any services here
        });
    });

await hostApplicationFactory.RunHostAsync();
```

This is assuming your host runs to completion and shuts down. You could also get `IHostApplicationLifetime` from your container to stop your application from your test.

The biggest gotcha to note here is in the override of `ConfigureWebHost`. The `builder.Configure(_ => { })` is needed to create an empty web application for `WebApplicationFactory`. Without it, you will get an error. Here's a link to the SO answer that helped me figure it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69974323/4465532

Hopefully this gets you started!